# Un nombre cardinal ou ordinal pour une date avec "à partir de"

Tags: dates

Est-ce que l'on dit `à partir du deux août` ou `à partir du deuxième août`? Quelle phrase est correcte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La première, *à partir du deux août*.

Answer (score 3):

Le premier du mois est le seul jour auquel on réfère avec un "ordinal", on dira donc *le premier août* mais *le deux août*. En fait ici, *le premier* n'est pas un ordinal, mais plutôt l'opposé de *dernier*.

Comment: Tu as évidemment raison auourd'hui. Noter tout de même que on a pourtant eu dit ainsi (jusqu'à fin XVIII au moins) en témoigne la 4è édition du DA https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie4/onzi%C3%A8me